# First non-zero value in a string regex

Tags: regex

since this morning I am struggling and seeking all over the internet (and of course SO) to find a solution for the following task:

Considering the strings:

```
'0012'
'1012'
'0111'
'0001'
```

How can I find the first non-zero number?
The output should be respectively:

```
'0012': 1
'1012': 1
'0111': 1
'0001': 1
```

Is there any RegEx wizard that can use some of his black magic to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have an example of data that should produce `0` (or 'not `1`') ? Which programming environment are you working with? Do you want to flag the first non-zero number or the first number not starting with the digit `0` ?

Comment: The example I proposed is a correct sample of the data I am dealing with.

Comment: @Seymour The question what we are asking to you - is to show non-matched use cases. Matches without non-matches doesn't make sense much.

Comment: @blhsing perfectly hit the point! Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex of `[1-9]` would match the first non-zero number.

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
^0*([1-9]).*$
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

That is we replace the whole string with what is within `()`; the first non-zero digit that comes after `0*` which matches 0 or any number of zeros and is followed by anything (we are not interested in that).

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and @blhsing one??

Comment: Mine is designed for find/replace and whereas his/hers works for match/extract only

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern `0{0,3}([1-9])\d{0,3}`