# How would regex that matches every number expect specifically '0'?

Tags: regex

I need regex that matches all numbers except "**0**". I tried using `[^0]+` but this one excludes number like 10, 50 and similar.

Comment: Try [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`(?!0)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/KY6Ewx/1/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630844/first-non-zero-value-in-a-string-regex

Answer (score 1):

To match any positive integer except zero:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

- `^` means assert start of string
- `\d*` means zero or more digits
- `$` means assert end of string

Note: this will not match values with leading zeros.

Comment: to match numbers with leading 0, you can add \d* at beginning : ^\d*[1-9]\d*$. It will match numbers such as 0005 but not 0, 00, 000...